# How can I apply Fisher-Yates-Knuth to Shuffling with restrictions? Or is there any other efficient approach?

Tags: c#, algorithm, shuffle

For example, i would like to shuffle 4 decks of cards, and make sure:

Any consecutive 4 cards won't come from the same deck.

Surely I can do the shuffling first and then filter out bad permutations, but if the restrictions are strong (e.g. any consecutive 2 cards won't come from the same deck) , there will be too many failures.

If i don't mind that if it is slightly unbiased, (of course the less bias the better), how should I do?

**Edit: Clarify**

Yes I want as uniformly as possible to pick from all full shuffles such that this additional criterion applied.

Comment: Why couldn't four consecutive cards come from the same deck?

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid constraint? In a truly random (honest) shuffle there could be any sequence of cards from 1 deck.

Comment: There's going to be a problem with anything as 'stateless' as normal FYK, in that if we are completely unconstrained to start with, we can get ourselves into a situation where there are only cards from one deck remaining, and we have more than 3 cards still to output. Right now I can't think of any way of avoiding the possibility that sometimes we will have to abort and restart. But then again algorithm-devisers are an inventive lot...

Comment: As clearly showed by dilbert: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: Anthony, Henk, I think asker wants to uniformly pick from all full shuffles *such that* this additional criterion applied.

Comment: Well, of course it causes bias, you are *asking* for bias as a feature.  Simply search for a card to swap that doesn't violate the requirement.  Always works with 4 decks.

Comment: @Hans No he isn't asking for bias as a feature. My understanding is that he wants uniform distribution among all configurations that satisfy the criterion.

Comment: If SO + a search of the literature doesn't turn anything up, you might consider looking and/or asking on [cstheory.se]

Comment: @CodeInChaos Which introduces bias in the final ordering of the cards with respect to all possible orderings of the cards, which I believe is Hans's point.

Comment: @colinfang Out of curiosity, why do you want/need this?

Answer (score 0):

I would process as below :

**First you can shuffle each 4 decks (using FYK algorithm)**

**Then generate a 4 partitions (* I define partition below) of your 52 cards of 4 decks** with the constraint of having not more than 3 element in each set of the partition :

For example :

```
(1,3,0,3,2,0,1) would be a partition of 10 with this constraint
(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) would be a partition of 10 too with this constraint
```

**Then Mix the 4 decks based on these partition.**

For example if you have :

```
(3,2,1)
(2,2,2)
```

you take the 3 first of deck one then 2 of deck 2 then 2 of deck one the 2 of deck 2 then 1 of deck 1 then 2 of deck 2. (okay ?)

All partitions are not valid, so you need to add one more constraint :

for example with this method :

```
(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1) 
(3,3,3)
```

will end up having 4 elements of deck 1 at the end.

**So the last partition must satisfy a constraint, I wrote a little python program to generate these partitions.**

```
from random import randint,choice

def randomPartition(maxlength=float('inf'),N=52): 
    '''
    the max length is the last constraint in my expanation:
      you dont want l[maxlength:len(l)]) to be more than 3
 in this case we are going to randomly add +1 to all element in the list that are less than 3

    N is the number of element in the partition
     '''
    l=[] # it's your result partition
    while(sum(l)<N ):
        if (len(l)>maxlength and sum(l[maxlength:len(l)])>=3): #in the case something goes wrong 
            availableRange=[i for i in range(len(l)) if l[i]<3] #create the list of available elements to which you can add one
            while(sum(l)<N):
                temp=choice(availableRange) #randomly pick element in this list
                l[temp]+=1
                availableRange=[i for i in range(len(l)) if l[i]<3] #actualize the list
                if availableRange==[]: #if this list gets empty your program cannot find a solution
                    print "NO SOLUTION" 
                    break
            break
        else:
            temp=randint(0,min(N-sum(l),3)) # If everything goes well just add the next  element in the list until you get a sum of N=52
            l.append(temp)
    return l
```

Now you can generate the 4 partitions and mix the decks according to these partitions :

```
def generate4Partitions():
    l1=randomPartition();
    l2=randomPartition();
    l3=randomPartition();
    m=max(len(l1),len(l2),len(l3))
    l4=randomPartition(m);
    return l1,l2,l3,l4
```

This 4 partitions will always be admissible based on their definitions.

**NOte:**

There might be more cases where it's not admissible , for example :

```
(3,0,0,3)
(0,3,3,0)
```

I guess this code needs to be modified a bit to take more constraints into account.

But it should be easy, just to delete unwanted zeros,like this:

```
(3,0,3)
(0,3,3,0)
```

Hope it's understandable and it helps

Comment: When you say "generate 4 partitions", you're actually generating more than that - you're partitioning the set into groups of at most 4.

Comment: @NickJohnson I am generating 4 groups of at most 4 that sum up to 52. I used the word partition because I used this groups to partition create a partition of the deck of cards. (before mixing them). All the decks play a symmetrical role, so the outcome should be pretty much uniform

Comment: If I read your answer correctly, you're generating an undefined number of partitions of at most four elements, not just four.

Comment: @NickJohnson I will try to clarify my answer when I have time, since it's not what I meant.